# FileReader JS Api Call Fire before it's ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filereader, angularjs-http

I'm trying to read a file, create a "FileContainer", and a DataUrl from a fileReader so i can send it to a web api.

My problem is that the Api call fires before my object is created, so i send Null to the api. which means that if i send a small file, it works.

My code for the reader look something like this

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
    return function (e) {
        var newFile = {
            name: theFile.name,
            type: theFile.type,
            size: theFile.size,
            lastModifiedDate: theFile.lastModifiedDate
        }
        var binaryString = e.target.result;
        updloadedFile(newFile, binaryString, selectedFolder, scope, fileProgrss);
        }
    };
})(f);
reader.readAsDataURL(f)
```

And for my http.post call

```
function updloadedFile(file, data, selectedFolder, scope, fileProgrss) {

    var dummyobj = {
        Name: file.name,
        Extension: file.name.split('.')[0],
        Path: selectedFolder.Path,
        DataString: data,
    }

    $http.post('/api/Files/Upload/',
      JSON.stringify(dummyobj),
      {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      }
  ).success(function (data2) {

  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  });
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, your `updloadedFile` gets called before your `reader.onload` is called if the file is big?

Comment: no, i think that the reader.onload is called first, curse i only call the updloadedFile inside it. But the binaryString only got it's value after the updloadedFile is called. so i somehow need to be sure the binaryString And newFile is done being created, before the updloadedFile  is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `FileReader` in a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
function fileReader(file) { // perform async operation
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      // Your reader.onload code here
      deferred.resolve(reader.result);
    };        

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);   
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

You can then call the `uploadedFile()` function like this:

```
fileReader().then(function(result){
  updloadedFile(..., ..., ..., ...)
});
```

By using the `promise` object, you can access the result of of the async task when it completes by using `then`.  `then` runs as soon the result is available.

If you want to read more about promises, this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604196/angularjs-where-to-use-promises) does a great job explaining it.

Comment: Cool. just tried, i gives me a error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $q is not defined`

Comment: You need to inject $q into the scope you are working with

Comment: app.controller("MyController",function($q){
    //$q is available here
})

Comment: Can i return more then one parms?
i need to get the new File and binaryString from my previous method. now i only get the binaryString curse of the reader.result

Comment: I sure this is the right way, curse now i get the dataUrl when is done. But as i said in the comment above. i need to get the newFile propertiesas well, an this i can't get to work

Comment: I think that you would probably have to create a new function which returns a promise. You would then have multiple functions returning promises, and you could then chain them using multiple `then`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357445/chain-promises-with-angularjs. Check both comments and you will get the general idea

Comment: will do, but i actually think my problem right now is that i can't get the file properties from the reader.onload like i did before. got any ideas to how i can get those values?

Comment: Hm. Could you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165919/filereader-not-loading-file-properly-using-angularjs

Comment: Yes, this help me, now i just need to combine the second then with this. and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the issue here is, you are listening to `onload`, apparantly it gets called on each read operation, thus might be null in beginning( [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)), try changing it to `onloadend`.

Comment: looks like onloadend does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the need for wrapping the FileReader API call within a promise. You could do that but according to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) `FileReader.onload` gets called when the data is ready. Doing a additional `deffered.resolved` to be able to use `then` is just a nice to have.

I have created a fiddle. Even with big files the http call is made only if the data is available.  I don't really see an error in your code. May you can try it out with the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/212/

Comment: That may be true. but after adjusting to the posted solutions, my code work.

Comment: Would be awesome to know the real problem.. :(

Comment: Well. i did make the post call before it had the data ready. an that was my problem. Why it did that, i can't tell. but the "nice to have" secured that the reader was done before posting. that all i can tell you