# Casting document.getElementById to access files in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload, typescript

I am very new to angularjs. I wasn't able to find the solution online. 
I would like to read the text from a file. I was trying to follow this example. 
[FileReader not loading file properly using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165919/filereader-not-loading-file-properly-using-angularjs)

However, since I'm using TypeScript, I receive this error for this line

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
```

Error:
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Please suggest me how I can cast to use the files.

Comment: it's not related to typescript, it's plain javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine from that example, maybe you're doing something wrong there. However, you may test your code like this, replace `fileChanged()` by `fileChanged(event)` and then get the files by `event.target.files`

```js
function fileChanged(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log(target.files);
  console.log(document.getElementById('fileInput').files);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input ng-model="csv"
            onchange="fileChanged(event)"
            type="file" id="fileInput"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. target.files seems to work. However , I am unable to implement like this document.getElementById('fileInput').files) . It seems to be working fine when debugging and I am getting the values but since I'm using TypeScript, its throwing me error when writing the code. Filereader is in lib.d.ts

Comment: I am still having another issue when trying to implement your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816670/function-is-not-defined-referecenerror-onchange-in-angularjs

Comment: I'll try to look into that issue, but never have worked on Kendo :(

Answer (score 12):

Another way I've found around the error in the question is to replace:

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
```

with

```
var input: any = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var file = input.files[0];
```

by defining input as type "any" the Typescript compiler no longer raises the error.

Answer (score 2):

you should cast it to `HTMLInputElement`. That interface has the `.files` field defined to be `FileList`

```
/**
 * Returns a FileList object on a file type input object.
 */
readonly files: FileList | null;

interface FileList {
    readonly length: number;
    item(index: number): File;
    [index: number]: File;
}
```