# Load JSON file in a browser

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I don't have much front-end experience, so please bear with me.

I have a local Angular app in browser (no back-end) and I want to upload a JSON file so that I can show the uploaded data on graphs. Since I don't know if I can just `fs.readFile` from Angular, I've chosen `ng-file-upload` to load the file in a nice way (from the file browser). Let me know if it isn't the right tool, though...

So I've copied the code from the official [JS Fiddle on the repo](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/). Had to modify it a bit to allow me upload anything -- remove validations.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('fileUploader', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
  $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
    $scope.f = file;
    $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    if (file) {
      file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {file: file}
      });

      file.upload.then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {  // don't know why this timeout 
         $scope.fileReady = true;
         file.result = response.data;

         // can't figure out what to do with this!!!
         console.log('response.data:\n', JSON.stringify(response.data.result, null, 2));
        });
      }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0)
          $scope.fileError = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The response comes out as an object I can't do much with:

```
 [
  {
    "fieldName": "file",
    "name": "my-awesome-data.json",
    "size": "364077"
  }
]
```

How do I get the actual data that was uploaded / parse the JSON file?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps `ng-file-uploader` is not the right tool for local files. Here's a much more simple solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165919/filereader-not-loading-file-properly-using-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Try to get the file content using $http.get like:

```
$http.get(response.data).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```